# Do I need to install a pump?

Tags: plumbing, sump-pump

I have lived in my home 20 years on high elevation with a very steep driveway. This house is about 25 years old. I have a below ground concrete floor basement. There is a sump pit but no pump. There has never been one because of elevation of lot. The mechanical engineer who inspected my home when purchasing it had said no I didn't need one.

I had my first incident of water in the basement. I was in this area on a Monday morning and it was completely dry. On Tuesday evening the area rugs I have down there were saturated. Most everything is up on shelves except a few storage boxes and bottom of those were wet. There was no standing water, concrete dry. I would not have even notice basement had been wet except for the saturated area rugs 10x12 rug and a smaller one.

There is water in the sump pit but below the level of drains that come through on inner sides, but only a few inches below. Do I need a sump pump? This is the first time this has happened. We did have a great deal of rain that Tuesday morning.

I've had 3 possible installers come out and look and give estimates. All three gave estimates but only one said absolutely you have to do it now since there's water that has to be pumped out. The other two said "wait and see since had not happened 20 years and elevation of my lot".

Any insight to what needs to be done?

Comment: Sump pumps are usually not expensive ~100 dollars.  Might turn out to be a 100 dollar paper weight, or something has changed.  They are usually nicer to have before you need them than after.  The more detail people can provide makes it easier for us.  Being why there is water on the floor as the total detail is useless to answer.

Comment: Check to make sure the land near the house slopes away, no new dips/low spots at/near the walls, and any down sprouts from the roof gutters drain away from the walls by a few feet.

Comment: How does the water actually get to the area where the rugs are? You also don't need a lot of rain to get lots of water ... I put a pump in for a small basement area and even on dry days it would go on every 30 minutes or so (needed 25+L to get to that point).

Comment: Don't ever apologize for providing what might be "extra" detail. We get so many questions with so little detail, it's a refreshing change! Unfortunately, though, I'm going to vote to close this as an opinion based question, which is off-topic here. You've had 3 professional opinions and received 2 different opinions, "Yes" and "No". We can't offer you anything more than more "yes" or "no" opinions. (con't...)

Comment: After 20 years there, it's up to you to decide if it's worth it to you to spend the money to install a sump pump. Things are usually designed to handle the "100 year flood", so you may have just had yours, or this may be a sign of things to come. BTW, if the drain plumbing is in place, it's ~$100 or so to buy a pump and probably 15 minutes to install it yourself if you're even moderately handy with a screwdriver and capable of inserting a plug into an outlet.

Answer (score 2):

If it is below grade and there is a pit for one you need a sump pump even if it never runs. If it rains and your carpets stayed dry you would have paid for it.

While you are at it see if you can determine where and how the water came in. Since the floor was wet I would assume the sump pump pit was full. It is possible water from your footer tiles ran into the pit and filled it up then the basement.

Something changed in the last 20 years, ground settling, record rainfall, failed eavestrough, etc. You need to determine what and repair it or expect more water.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if your basement is above or below ground, what matters is where the drain pipe goes to.

You probably don't need a pump. You say you are on a hillside so it's conceivable that the drain slopes downwards from below the basement floor to the surface of the ground (further down the hill)

Find out where the drain flows to, and check that it is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Before you install a pump, consider this cheep effective sensors, that will alert you of a problem.

I have these in my home at ever possible leak location (dishwasher, washing machine ect.)

[image: water sensor]

The nice part is you will get an alert on your phone at only 1/8 of inch water level.

Pre requisite is you have to have Internet (WiFi)

Automated drain pump is nice to have if it happens frequently at your place.

Comment: Great advice, but doesn't answer the question.